# public ip to private ip translation in sonicwall.working with wan1 not working with wan2.please suggest

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, sonicwall

we are using soincwall tz210 firewall.We have two wan connections,from wan1(x0) we have created one policy with http.we can connect from out side networks by using wan1ip,but another wan2(x3) is not communicating from out side networks.unable to login from outside networks .please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Every NAT Policy gets assigned to specific interface (both IN and OUT). Also, depending on your firewall configurations, you will probably have to create an Access Rule to match your NAT Policy. Make sure to create it in the appropriate zone (WAN to WAN, WAN to LAN - depending on what you need).

One last thing, every interface has a custom setting - whether to allow `http,https,ssh` management connections on it - please make sure to check the ones you need (if that's what you want).